# LightGBM install error r, unable to troubleshoot

Tags: r, lightgbm

This is the error that I am getting. I also tried all the other install options on their website and no luck. I am kind of lost on how I should trouble shoot this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 > install_github("Microsoft/LightGBM", subdir = "R-package")
 Downloading GitHub repo Microsoft/LightGBM@master
 from URL https://api.github.com/repos/Microsoft/LightGBM/zipball/master
 Installing lightgbm
 Installing 1 package: data.table
 Installing package into ‘C:/Users/XXXXXXXXXX/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
 (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
 trying URL 
 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/data.table_1.10.4-3.zip'
 Content type 'application/zip' length 1577027 bytes (1.5 MB)
 downloaded 1.5 MB

 package ‘data.table’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
 Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package ‘data.table’

 The downloaded binary packages are in

 C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpa409YJ\downloaded_packages
 "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --
 no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL "C:/Users/XXXXXX  \
  XXXXX/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpa409YJ/devtools15b8405627ba/Microsoft-
LightGBM-04d4811/R-package" --library="C:/Users/XXXXXXXXX  \
  XXXXXXXXX/Documents/R/win-library/3.4" --install-tests 

 ERROR: dependency 'data.table' is not available for package 'lightgbm'
* removing 'C:/Users/XXXXXXXXXX/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/lightgbm'
Installation failed: Command failed (1)
Warning message:
GitHub repo contains submodules, may not function as expected! 


R.Version() 
$platform
[1] "x86_64-w64-mingw32"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "mingw32"

$system
[1] "x86_64, mingw32"

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "3"

$minor
[1] "4.1"

$year
[1] "2017"

$month
[1] "06"

$day
[1] "30"

$`svn rev`
[1] "72865"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)"

$nickname
[1] "Single Candle"
```

Stackoverlfow thinks that this post has to much code so I need to add more text to it so I am going to ramble on here about nothing so I can hit the character limit. I am bitterly sorry if you are reading this because I am wasting your time as well as my time writing this but systems are systems so I guess I just have to keep going. Kind of like Dory in finding Nemo. Just keep swimming, just keep swimming.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this by going into R studio and installing the data.table package. I had the same problem and this worked for me

Comment: just realized this was 1 year ago :/